# jquery get attr() method and appendTo html

Tags: jquery, attributes, navigation, appendto

I trying to get the id of my **sections** and append the id attribute to the clicked button.

so it will show:

```
<div class="navigate-left">PREVIEW ID NAME SECTION</div>

<div class="navigate-right">NEXT ID NAME SECTION</div>
```

Any help would be  much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/67/

```
$('.navigate-left').click(function() {
 $(this).attr('id').appendTo($('.navigate-left'));
});

$('.navigate-right').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id').appendTo($('.navigate-right'));
});
```

Comment: i don't see anything with class `left` and `right`

Comment: Don't see any button either

Comment: If you inspect the buttons navigations you'll see it!

Comment: THE black Arrow right

Comment: they are divs not button and have class navigate-left or navigate-right not .right/left

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/65/

Comment: @Anton thanks for pointing it out, I had to put together a fiddle and I miss out that. could you help me?

Comment: `.appendTo($('button .left'));` where is button? and .left? in the click function

Comment: @Anton yes like that. http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/67/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some looking, I found that the current `section` has the class `present`. So, you can get the current section's id by using the below code.

```
$('.navigate-left').click(function () {
     var currentSection = $('section.present');
     var prevId = currentSection.prev('section').attr('id');
     var nextId = currentSection.next('section').attr('id');

     $(this).text(prevId);
     $('.navigate-right').text(nextId);

 });

 $('.navigate-right').click(function () {
     var currentSection = $('section.present');
     var prevId = currentSection.prev('section').attr('id');
     var nextId = currentSection.next('section').attr('id');

     $('.navigate-left').text(prevId);
     $(this).text(nextId);
 });
```

EDIT: The below demo gives you the ids of the previous & next sections below the arrows

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/72/)***

Comment: and how can I append it?

Comment: var sectionId = $('section.present').attr('id');
 console.log($('section.present').attr('id'))
works:-)

Comment: negative feedback? @user2505665

Comment: @Krishna sorry I think your fiddle hasn't saved its an old one

Comment: @Anton - thank you. copy paste error. @ OP - where do you want to append it?

Comment: @Krishna you still there?

Comment: @user2505665 - check out my latest EDIT & DEMO.. thats probably what you want or feel free to modify according to your needs.

Comment: super annoying! What :-(